# Mui Select component throwing out of range value in a dynamicy selec component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have the following issue regarding select component that is dynamic and filters the selected value so a user cannot use the same value twice how ever at the current implementing I am getting out of range value want I add specific values what is causing this issue and how to prevent the error for showing up ?

```js
const groupsOptions = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
 const addedValue = // this will give already existing value that have been already added 
 const currentOptions = [...groupsOptions].filter((el) => !addedValue?.includes(el));
 
 <FormControl>
  <Select value={currentValue} onChange={handleChange}>
    <MenuItem value='' >
      <Typography>
       Values
      </Typography>
    </MenuItem>
    {currentOptions.map((el, i) => (
      <MenuItem key={i} value={el}>{el}</MenuItem>
    ))}
  </Select>
</FormControl>
```

Erorr massage is

> Material-UI: You have provided an out-of-range value `a` for the select component.
> Consider providing a value that matches one of the available options or ''.
> The available values are ``, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, `g`.

Answer (score 1):

You might get this error because you are mapping over options and showing them in `MenuItem` while these options aren't yet loaded. **try :**

```
</MenuItem>
    {currentOptions && currentOptions.map((el, i) => (
      <MenuItem key={i} value={el}>{el}</MenuItem>
```